# How do I specify intermediate certs in concourse ATC?

Tags: concourse

I have an arbitrary long cert chain that I want to use to verify my ATC, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cert file you can append your certs together to make a chain.
Example:

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDrTCCAxagAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADCBnDEbMBkGA1UEChMSVGhl
IFNhbXBsZSBDb21wYW55MRQwEgYDVQQLEwtDQSBEaXZpc2lvbjEcMBoGCSqGSIb3
................................................................
<More of cert 1>
................................................................
FS5G13pW2ZnAlSdTkSTKkE5wGZ1RYSfyiEKXb+uOKhDN9LnajDzaMPkNDU2NDXDz
SqHk9ZiE1boQaMzjNLu+KabTLpmL9uXvFA/i+gdenFHv
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDrTCCAxagAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADCBnDEbMBkGA1UEChMSVGhl
IFNhbXBsZSBDb21wYW55MRQwEgYDVQQLEwtDQSBEaXZpc2lvbjEcMBoGCSqGSIb3
................................................................
<More of cert 2>
................................................................
FS5G13pW2ZnAlSdTkSTKkE5wGZ1RYSfyiEKXb+uOKhDN9LnajDzaMPkNDU2NDXDz
SqHk9ZiE1boQaMzjNLu+KabTLpmL9uXvFA/i+gdenFHv
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDrTCCAxagAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADCBnDEbMBkGA1UEChMSVGhl
IFNhbXBsZSBDb21wYW55MRQwEgYDVQQLEwtDQSBEaXZpc2lvbjEcMBoGCSqGSIb3
................................................................
<More of cert n>
................................................................
FS5G13pW2ZnAlSdTkSTKkE5wGZ1RYSfyiEKXb+uOKhDN9LnajDzaMPkNDU2NDXDz
SqHk9ZiE1boQaMzjNLu+KabTLpmL9uXvFA/i+gdenFHv
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`